# How to validate scanner input using a different method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner

public class Editable {

/* Return true if amount is within MIN_AMOUNT and MAX_AMOUNT 
*/
public static boolean isValidAmount(double amount) {
    return amount > MIN_AMOUNT && amount < MAX_AMOUNT;
}

/* Asks user to input amount until isValidAmount is true.
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(system.in);

}
```

I'm new to Java and I've been struggling with this for quite a bit. 
I'm asking for user input in main and I need it to keep asking for user input until isValidAmount returns true. I have tried multiple different solutions but can't seem to get it to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double inputAmount = 0;
    try {
        while (!isValidAmount(inputAmount)) {
            System.out.println("Enter amount:");
            inputAmount = scanner.nextDouble();
            scanner.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Input error.");
        scanner.next();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "can't seem to get it to work" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you only need a `nextDouble`. `scanner.next()` would read the next value and discard it. Also, try using a `do while` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double inputAmount = 0;
    try {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter amount:");
            inputAmount = scanner.nextDouble();
        } while (!isValidAmount(inputAmount));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Input error.");
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

I think perhaps your `inputAmount` was already a valid value before prompting the user. The `do while` loop will always execute the statements between the brackets before checking the condition. The `while` loop will no execute the statements in the brackets if the condition is already false.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for me. scanner.next() might have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out `scanner.next();`. You don't need it. Your program is perfect otherwise. (I am assuming that `MIN_AMOUNT` is declared to be > 0).